# Pass object to javascript function from ejs

Tags: javascript, ejs

I'm trying to attach a click event from my ejs file but I noticed that when my data coming from my database has a "newline", I get an error that says: `Unexpected token in JSON at position 253`

app.js

```
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
   return res.render('page', {
      data: dataArray
   })
});
```

page.ejs:

```
  <% for(let t of data) { %>
  <tr class="tr-<%= t.id %>">
    <td><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt" onclick="editT('<%= JSON.stringify(t) %>')"></i>
    </td>
    <td><%= t.name %></td>
    <td><%= t.description %></td>
  </tr>
  <% } %>
```

script

```
function editT(t) {
  t = JSON.parse(t);
  console.log(t)
}
```

When a description has a "newline" and I use `JSON.stringif(t)` it comes broken:

```js
let t = '{"id":1,"name":"Lorem","description":"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry!

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
","created_at":"2022-04-18T22:19:00.153Z"}';


console.log(JSON.parse(treatment));
```

Comment: Use `String.raw` to escape all escape sequences, so that when you pass it to your template, it gets interpreted properly.

Comment: Why would you use a legacy `onclick` with a full data embed, instead of loading the JSON from file (which can _also_ be services using EJS, just as a separate route!) so your client-side code can work with it the same way it works with everything else JS related? Even if you absolutely want it all in one file: stick the JSON in a `<script id="myJSONdata" type="application/json">......</script>` and then make JS work with it by pulling from ```document.querySelector(`#myJSONdata`).textContent``` once it's time to run your `addEventListener` code (using the `defer` attribute, of course)

Answer (score 0):

there two way of doing this without error

first one using `<%- %>` this way it will write the unescaped string

like this :

```
<td><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt" onclick="editT('<%- JSON.stringify(t)%>')"></i></td>
```

second one would be using encode

```
<td><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt" onclick="editT('<%= encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(t))%>')"></i></td>
```

the second one also requires you to do

```
function editT(t) {
  t = JSON.parse( decodeURIComponent(t));
  console.log(t)
}
```